# How to securely add a secret api key to a website which makes API calls to server?

Tags: authentication, flask, restful-authentication

So, I have a flask server running on an instance. I have a simple setup for authentication. Clients send `@key=my_secret_apikey` in API call and I do the verification on the server.

I have minimal frontend knowledge. I have a website which calls this endpoint which needs authentication. If I embed the API key `my_secret_apikey` on the site, it's visible to everyone in script section which exposes the key to public.

How to make authenticated API calls from website to API server without showcasing API key?

My current setup is: Have an API key only for the website and while authenticating, if I get this API key I used on the site, I'll check `request.environ.get("HTTP_ORIGIN")` which returns `https://www.my_site.com` and if that matches my site, it'll send the response or the authentication fails.

Is there any better way to do this whole authentication and API key thing?

Comment: You might want to consult [this article for doing just that.](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-securely-store-api-keys-4ff3ea19ebda)

Comment: No. This question is not about securing API keys. How to securely add them to website javascript without compromising authentication.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35530/where-and-how-to-store-private-keys-in-web-applications-for-private-messaging-wi